# Need to validate for invalid xml characters in SWT/AWT Text box

Tags: java, textbox, swt, awt

I have a window that has textbox, with OK and Cancel buttons.
upon clicking Ok button, I need to validate the entered text contains invalid xml characters and show a warning popup message.

I am able to perform this by getting text.getText(). However, if tomorrow a new SWT/AWT Textbox appears in the window, again i will have to modify code to get the getText() from the new control.

Is there a generic method so that, when a new SWT/AWT Textbox is added in that window, we can enforce to validate this invalid xml character check ?

Answer (score 0):

Use SWT.Verify event type. Create one listener that does the XML character check and add that listener to all the Textbox in the window.

Here is a [SWT snippe](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet19.java)t that shows the use of SWT.Verify event